# Jquery - "Pie" Menu PlugIn

Tags: jquery, menu

did anybody know a nice (and stable) Pie menu like this
[image]

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Comment: I've never seen anything like that, do you know of a site that has something similar?

Comment: check this -> http://www.google.de/search?um=1&hl=de&biw=1680&bih=915&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=jquery+pie|circle+menu&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=

Comment: BTW: i can program this menue, but my mainproblem is to create a div with 5 corners... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen menus that supporting submenus. The closest thing to your question I saw is http://www.cs.tut.fi/~laine9/demo/ppmenu/piedemo.html

I believe you can add submenu support here by binding events to menu item